# Unit testing Spring REST API Service (Update (PUT Method))

Tags: java, spring, api, unit-testing, http

I'm trying to unit test a service for my controller in my API but i'm getting the following error :

```css
2020-05-20 15:23:51.493  WARN 25469 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.tropicalia.meu_cardapio.domain.user.User> com.tropicalia.meu_cardapio.api.user.update.UserUpdateRest.update(com.tropicalia.meu_cardapio.domain.user.User,java.lang.Long)]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /users/89
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.tropicalia.meu_cardapio.api.user.update.UserUpdateRest
           Method = com.tropicalia.meu_cardapio.api.user.update.UserUpdateRest#update(User, Long)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :202
Actual   :400
```

This is my test class :

```css
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserUpdateRest.class)
public class UpdateUserTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserUpdateService service;

    @Test
    public void updateUser_whenPutUser() throws Exception {

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test Name");
        user.setId(89L);

        given(service.updateUser(user.getId(), user)).willReturn(user);

        mvc.perform(put("/users/" + user.getId().toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("name", is(user.getName())));
    }
}
```

And this is my service

```css
@Service
public class UserUpdateService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User updateUser(Long id, User user) {
        repository
                .findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User not found."));
        return repository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this one.

From what i understand, there's something wrong with the request body but i have no idea what to do to fix it.

Comment: Hi, if you can share your `Controller` and the `User` class, that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: You need to add User object as well in the mock mvc request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the error message, `requestbody` is missing.

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

All you need to do is add body content to the unit test like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mvc.perform(put("/users/" + user.getId().toString())
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user))
      .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("name", is(user.getName())));
```

you can also pass content like this

```
.content("{\"id\":\"89\", \"name\":\"Test Name\"}")
```

Comment: Thank you!! You are correct and my problem is now fixed :)